# Java automatically format date info. in other language

Tags: linux, java, locale

My system is Linux 64bit, and my JDK is *icedtea*. My system can display Chinese, but it is not set as the primary language of the system, nor for the desktop environment. But when I run java applications, it automatically formats the date object using Chinese...weird.

How can I force java to use the primary system language to format date objects, if the formatting language is not set in the application?

Comment: Can you include the output of `locale` command in your question?

Comment: the `locale` says my LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"...i see the problem. thanks

Comment: @davidshen84 recommend you post as answer if you see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the problem is caused by the setting of your Linux system locale. In my case, the `LC_CTYPE` was set to **zh_CN.UTF-8**. Simply set it to **en_US.UTF-8** solves my problem.